# Trigger Compilation Issues - Oracle 10g

Tags: triggers, compiler-errors, oracle10g

I am trying to create a trigger that when a user inserts into a table, the trigger will join with another table and insert into the primary one. Here is the trigger I have created so far. When I insert it into the database I get "Warning: Trigger Created with Compilation Errors."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TBI_PERSONS_IDM_STAGING
AFTER INSERT
ON PERSONS_IDM_STAGING 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF :new.PERSON NOT IN (SELECT PERSON FROM PERSONS) AND INSERTING 
  THEN
INSERT INTO PERSONS (
        PERSON, 
        DBLOGIN_ID, 
        LAST_NAME, 
        FIRST_NAME, 
        DEPARTMENT, 
        JOBTITLE, 
        USERLEVEL, 
        FACILITY_ID, 
        USER_OPTIONS, 
        PASSWORD)
VALUES(:new.PERSON, 
       :new.PERSON, 
       :new.LAST_NAME, 
       :new.FIRST_NAME, 
       :new.DEPARTMENT, 
       :new.JOBTITLE, 
       :new.USERLEVEL, 
       (SELECT KMS_FACILITY_ID FROM FACILITY_IDM_STAGING WHERE FACILITY_IDM_STAGING.IDM_CODE = :new.IDM_CODE), 
       :new.USER_OPTIONS, 
       :new.PASSWORD);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I was able to fix the code. Here is the correct statement if anyone else has this issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TAI_PERSONS_IDM_STAGING
AFTER INSERT
ON PERSONS_IDM_STAGING 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PERSONS (
            PERSON, 
            DBLOGIN_ID, 
            LAST_NAME, 
            FIRST_NAME, 
            DEPARTMENT, 
            JOBTITLE, 
            USERLEVEL, 
            FACILITY_ID, 
            USER_OPTIONS, 
            PASSWORD)
    VALUES(:new.PERSON, 
           :new.PERSON, 
           :new.LAST_NAME, 
           :new.FIRST_NAME, 
           :new.DEPARTMENT, 
           :new.JOBTITLE, 
           :new.USERLEVEL, 
           (SELECT KMS_FACILITY_ID FROM FACILITY_IDM_STAGING WHERE FACILITY_IDM_STAGING.IDM_CODE = :new.IDM_CODE), 
           :new.USER_OPTIONS, 
           :new.PASSWORD);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you're using SQL*Plus, type `show errors` to have SQL*Plus show you the compilation errors.

Comment: The errors were 'PL/SQL: Statement Ignored' and 'PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context.'

Comment: Any ideas how to get around the subquery? I'm not having any luck.